# How do you create a new column whose values are the hex strings of an existing ByteArray column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that currently looks like this:

```
Date      ByteArray
1/2/2019  bytearray([21,24,120,3,32,32,0,215])
2/1/2019  bytearray([24,22,115,4,35,31,0,216])
```

My goal is to get to get a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Date      ByteArray                            Hex String
1/2/2019  bytearray([21,24,120,3,32,32,0,215]) 15 18 78 03 20 20 00 D7
2/1/2019  bytearray([24,22,115,4,35,31,0,216]) 18 16 73 04 23 1F 00 D8
```

I know that outside of pandas, if I had single bytearray I wanted to convert I could do this:

```
y=bytearray([24,22,115,4,35,31,0,216])
print((' '.join(format(x, '02x') for x in y)).upper())
```

But I am not sure how to do this with pandas/dataframes. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be a better (faster) way using built-in Pandas functions that I'm not aware of, but with `apply`, you can apply an arbitrary Python function to your data. The code below simply applies the code snippet you provided to each element in your column:

```
df['Hex String'] = df['ByteArray'].apply(lambda y: ' '.join(format(x, '02x') for x in y).upper())
```